# How to see comments & posts I've upvoted in Hacker News

Tags: hacker-news

Is it possible to find all the comments & posts I've upvoted?

I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Comments are available at https://news.ycombinator.com/threads?id=username. Not possible to find find those you've upvoted, atleast not without use of API

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to fetch all comments you've upvoted - the link is `https://news.ycombinator.com/saved?id=<your ID>`

Comment: This is wrong - see my answer at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118902/190993 for the right link.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://news.ycombinator.com/upvoted?id=[your_username]&comments=t (linked to from your profile).